# NPM Package path is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, es6-modules

I'm attempting to building my first NPM package for educational purposes, and I've been stuck in the manuals and looking at other projects for hours now trying to make things work.

#### Project setup

[image: Project directory structure]

My package builds successfully and from what I can tell all files are generated respectively for ESM and CommonJS targets.

The package also installs successfully using both `yarn` and `npm`, I tried both flavors just to make sure I'm not targeting one or the other. My "successfully" means the package installs with all green, and appears under `node_modules`.

But when I try to use any object from my project I get an error saying the module is not exported:

```js
// Load application object and attach UX
import {app} from "@myproject/package/src/Application";
document.body.onload = () => {
    app.attachUx(document.body);
};

// Compiler error:
// Module not found: Error: Package path ./src/Application is not exported from package
```

#### Target environment

Assuming I understand "npm packages" correctly, the IDE shouldn't be importing `@myproject/package/src/Application` but rather `@myproject/package/Application` since the compile target should "decide" if it uses TypeScript sources, `dist/cjs` for CommonJS or `dist/esm` for Emac?

If I do understand NPM package targeting correctly, the `export.import` entry should be used when used by a "emac"-target, and `export.require` used by an "CommonJS" target?

#### Finally

Why is nothing from my project exported? NPM doesn't recognize any file or definition, meaning I have tried each combination of the following lines to import my `Application`:

```js
import {app} from "@myproject/package/src/Application";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/src/Application.js";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/Application";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/Application.js";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/dist/cjs/Application";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/dist/cjs/Application.js";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/dist/esm/Application";
import {app} from "@myproject/package/dist/esm/Application.js";
```

### Solution

Thank you @morganney for indicating that the exports entry needs to be more precise. I finally ended up with the exports entry below, which works on any scenario including

- Importing from node, ESM and CJS
- Explicit /dist import for ESM and CJS
- Explicit /src import for TypeScript sources
- Works for type hinting in IDE's such as PHPStorm and VSCode

```json
    "exports": {
        "./*": {
            "import": "./dist/esm/*.js",
            "require": "./dist/cjs/*.js",
            "node": "./src/*.ts"
        },
        "./dist/*": {
            "import": "./dist/esm/*",
            "require": "./dist/cjs/*"
        },
        "./src/*": "./src/*.ts"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your build is correct, the thing that stands out is your `files` definition in your package.json. That should probably be changed to

```json
"files": ["dist"]
```

Since that is where your build output is going, at least based on your `exports` definition since you haven't shared your tsconfig.json files.

You should probably update your `exports` to be more specific about the conditional subpaths you want to use. It doesn't seem you have one primary index export, and so try something like this:

```json
"exports": {
  "import": {
    "./Application.js": "./dist/esm/Application.js"
  },
  "require": {
    "./Application.js": "./dist/cjs/Application.js"
  }
}
```

Then you should update your `import` statements to look like this:

```js
import {app} from '@mypackage/Application.js'
```

Finally, you can simplify your dual build by needing less npm run scripts and only one tsconfig.json file if you try [`@knighted/duel`](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel). Your updated build script would look like this:

```json
"build": "npm run clean && npm run duel --dirs"
```

Comment: Well, that "works" but, but both VSCode and PHPStorm don't understand the import if I do that. However, it compiles and Webpack is able to recognize my library. If I change the import to `import {app} from "@mypackage"` VSCode and PHPStorm recognizes the type, but Webpack is back to not compiling again due to "package path is not exported from package". I get one or the other to work, not both (webpack compile + IDE type hinting).

Comment: Note: VSCode don't understand anything if it compile, but PHPStorm recognizes "somehting", and wants to import `@mypackage/src/Application`, but that's not right, it shouldn't be detecting sub-paths.

Comment: You’re doing something wrong, but hard to say what unless you share more details.

Comment: Actually, I got it working by being more specific as you said. I was attempting to be too generic I guess, I wanted 3 versions to be available at once, the original (TypeScript), and both ESM/CJS targets. When I only target ESM/CJS it works. Guess TypeScript breaks something if it's part of the same bundle.

Comment: Nice, thumbs up.

Comment: Is this a rule that you have to explicitly set them to specific instead of using * in public_api ?

Comment: A packages entry points can use wildcards. The updated OP even provides an example. Check the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points